# How can I find the partial transpose for three qubit density matrix usign mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, quantum-computing, qubit

I know that the density matrix of a three-qubit is an 8x8 matrix. How can I use Mathematica to find the partial transpose of this 8x8 matrix with respect to the first, second, or the third qubit?